# How to "finally" on promise with then/catch?

Tags: javascript

How to do a proper finally on a promise?

Can I add a finally equivalent to this?

```
functionReturningPromise()
   .then(success => {})
   .catch(error => {})
```

or should I do it this way (does this even work as expected)?

```
functionReturningPromise()
   .then(success => {},error => {}).then(() => { /* finally code */ })
```

Comment: `.finally`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

Comment: Your first method is just fine. You can add `.finally` after your `.catch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
.finally()
```

Example:

```
functionReturningPromise()
.then(data=>console.log(data))
.catch(error=>console.log(error))
.finally(()=>console.log("FINISH"))
```

The finally is called allways

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Use finally from [Promise.prototype.finally()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally)

```
yourPromiseFunction
  .then(function(json) { /* process your JSON further */ })
  .catch(function(error) { console.log(error); /* this line can also throw, e.g. when console = {} */ })
  .finally(function() { console.log("finally") });
```

2. Or you can add an additional then() after the catch() to do finally in all the browsers.

Example:

```
yourPromiseFunction.then(() => console.log('Resolved'))
            .catch(() => console.log('Failed'))
            .then(() => console.log('This is your finally'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, finally works with promises.

Example:

```
let isLoading = true;

fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
        var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
        if (contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
    })
    .then(function(json) {
        /* process your JSON further */
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error); /* this line can also throw, e.g. when console = {} */
    })
    .finally(function() {
        isLoading = false;
    });
```

For further reference refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally